# React / useEffect doesn't call/dispatch action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux

This should work ->

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import CheckLoginStatus from "../../utils/CheckLoginStatus";
import ProductDetailDisplay from '../../components/product/ProductDetailDisplay'

// using @reduxjs/toolkit as Redux state / store thing
import { selectProduct, getProductById } from '../products/productsSlice'
    
function handleAddToCart(){
    alert('handleAddToCart')
}

export default function ProductDetail ( props ) {
    let { productId } = props
    CheckLoginStatus()

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const productData = useSelector(selectProduct)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect()') // <<< 'useEffect()' appears in console
        dispatch(getProductById(productId)); // <<< it looks like it's never called
    },[])

    return <ProductDetailDisplay data={productData} handleAddToCart={ handleAddToCart }/>
}
```

However, the 'dispatch(getProductById(productId))' inside of useEffect doesn't happen. (edit) However, the  console.log('useEffect()') line does execute, and the message appears in the console.

I've been staring at this for an entire day, trying out all of the combinations of solutions I can think of, and have nothing.

Can someone please let me know where I'm missing the point with this code? It should work, and a single product record should be available to ProductDetailDisplay. But it looks like 'getProductById(productId))' never gets called.

Thanks in advance.

(edit) krirkrirk, here is the code for getProductById ->

```
export const getProductById = createAsyncThunk (
    'products/getProductById',
    async (product_id) => {  
        let theApiUrl = API_BASE_URL + `/api/v1/product/${product_id}`
        let authToken = useSelector(selectJwtToken)

        console.log('getProductById', product_id)

        try { 
            const response = await fetch(
                theApiUrl,
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': "*/*",
                            'Content-Type': "application/json",
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`,
                        },
                        credentials: 'include',
                }
            )

            let data = await response.json();

            if (response.status === 200) {
                // console.log('getProductById 200', data[0]) 
                console.log('productById ', data)
                return data[0] // FIXME: shouldn't have to juggle arrays when assigning to state...
            } else if (response.status === 401) {
                console.log('getProductById get request auth fail.')
                // return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(data)
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error: ", e.response.data)
            // return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response.data)
        }
    }
) // end getProductById
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for getProductById please

Comment: you should add useEffect dependencies if you want to run useEffect once you can add empty array as dependency, like this -> useEffect(()=>{ //your code }, []);

Comment: krirkrirk: getProductById code is added to the message

Comment: barzin, I tried the empty array after posting this, but it didn't work. However, I edited the post above to include the empty array.

Comment: How do you know that the action isn't dispatched? If the useEffect callback function fails, there would usually be an error message in your javascript console. Also, what does `CheckLoginStatus` do? If it's not relevant for your issue, please remove it. If you can make a [mcve], you're much more likely to get an answer here. That means removing any code from your code sample that is not relevant to your bug.

Comment: I know that the action isn't dispatched because:
- the request to the server that it should make never shows up in the server console
- Redux console (dev tools in Chrome) doesn't show the action being dispatched
- the product info doesn't get added to the Redux store

Also, if I take the useEffect code away, and just leave the dispatch(getProductById(productId));

the code runs in a loop.

So I know it works, the problem is getting it to run only when the component renders, which it isn't doing